# Why wont my image load in the bottom middle of the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm following a book to create a space invader game as I started learning python recently. I can't make the ship appear at the bottom middle of the screen. I have code that should do that but it starts the ship at the bottom left. If I move the code further down then the ship goes to the right place but it then won't move when the game is run.

Here is the code I am using. I have put two comments in the ship file that show the two places I have tried the code:

this is a file called alieninvasion

```
import sys#tools to make and quit game

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """manage assets and behaviour"""

    def __init__(self):
        """initialise game and create resources"""
        pygame.init()#initialises setting for pygame to work
        self.settings = Settings()#creates an instance

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        #placed in settings method instead
        #self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        
    def run_game(self):
        """start main game loop"""
        while True:
        #watch for keyboard and mouse events
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()#updates to check for key change
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """respond to keypresses and mouse events"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():#event is key press or mouse
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:#allows you to close the window by pressing X in topright
                sys.exit()
            #basically, if click right then move right and same for left
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:#keydown is if key pressed
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = True

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _update_screen(self):
        """update images ons creen and flip to new screen"""
            #redraw screen during each pass through loop
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        #make most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__  == '__main__':
    #makes a game instance and runs game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()

#https://pixabay.com/ = free pixel website
# want in bitmap (.bmp) file as pygames uses it by default
```

settings file

```
class Settings:
    """class to store settings"""
    def __init__(self):
        """initialise game settings"""
        #screen settings
        #set bg colour, 3 variables of RBG, 0-255
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (100, 10, 150)#black is default so change it

    #ship settings
        self.ship_speed = 1.5 #moves 1.5 pixels each time
```

ship file, theres 2 comments for where I've tried this line: self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    """class to manage ship"""
#in pygame,the origin (0,0) is top left of screen

    def __init__(self, ai_game):#putting ai_game gives it access to all game resources
        """initialise ship and set start position"""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        #load ship image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #start each new ship at bottom center of screen
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
#        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom#------------------book says to put code here but goes to bot left

        #movement flags
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False



    def update(self):
        """"update ship position based on flag movment"""
        #update ships x value if not rect
        if self.moving_right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

        #update rect object from self.x
        self.rect.x = self.x
        
#        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom-----------here,ship is in the right place but wont move
    def blitme(self):
        """draw ship at current location"""
        #draws image to screen at position specified by self.rect
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)#rect means rectangle
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `self.x` after you have set `self.rect.midbottom`:

```py
class Ship:
    # [...]

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        # [...]

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        # [...]
```

Note, `midbottom` is a virtual attribute of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object and actually changed `rect.x` and `rect.y`.